# Is LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing supported by UnboundID LDAP SDK?

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Relatively recently Microsoft has added support for LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing:

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/ADV190023

Is it part of LDAPv3 protocol?
Is it supported by UnboundID LDAP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the advisory is that these are not LDAPv3 specific, but more settings of the server and the underlying security libraries.

The support they have added is on the server side to verify that LDAP signing is enabled on the security layer before allowing Simple or SASL authentication. Most LDAP servers on the market support that. And the UnboundID LDAP SDK has support for enabling this from the client side.

LDAP Channel binding is again not fully LDAPv3 specific, but also tied to tokens generated and used by MS AD, over LDAP. I don't think there's anything specific to do on the client side, beside using TLS/SSL.

Comment: I a little confused: Are there any LDAP implementations that use "LDAP Signing" that are not using a SASL mechanism?

Comment: The confusion comes from Microsoft terminology. Here's how they consider "LDAP signing": <quote>The security of a directory server can be significantly improved by configuring the server to reject Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL) LDAP binds that do not request signing (integrity verification) or to reject LDAP simple binds that are performed on a clear text (non-SSL/TLS-encrypted) connection. </quote>.
Signing is a way to ensure integrity of messages, it can be achieved with TLS or SASL.